# PHP E-Commerce Page Loop Not Listing Items as Expected

Tags: php, html

I'm building a script which populates a page with products. Under each product is a "Buy" button. I looped through the products from the database, and the name and price and all other info turns up correctly. However, when I try to input that same info into the form with hidden fields I only get back the data from the first item from the list. Let me show you:

```
<div class="product-foo">
     //Shows up fine
     <p><?php echo product->name; ?></p> 
     <p><?php echo product->price; ?></p>
     <p><?php echo product->info; ?></p>

    //Only first iteration's info gets submitted, no matter which button I click
    <form method="post">
         <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $product->name; ?>" > 
         <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="<?php echo $product->price; ?>" >
         <input type="hidden" name="product_info" value="<?php echo $product->info; ?>" >
         <button type="submit" name="finalpost" class="btn btn-primary">Get Product</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I thought that each form would be different, so when I clicked on a button on an item only the info for that item would go through, but it's always submitting the first item. I figure it may not work how I'm thinking it should work, but can anyone tell me why this is so and how I can easily resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code for you button:

```
 <button type="submit" name="finalpost" class="btn btn-primary">Get Product</button>
```

It looks like you were missing the trailing > after your class definition.  I suspect the 'view source' of the page would have showed all data, but since you broke the HTML it was being hidden from the browser view.

Another thing to consider - can you use:

```
  <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
```

instead of:

```
 <button>
```

to further test?  I suspect this will submit the right form data, but may not be acceptable if your button is calling JS and is doing more than submitting form data.

Comment: Thanks i corrected the typo but that wasn't the issue. Your suggestion for using page source was great though, and it leads me into more stupor because I definitely see that the forms all should have the right info.

Comment: Can you post the entire page source?  I've seen similar issues when I wasn't properly closing elements in the html.  Viewing the entire output of the form code should be enough to let me see what is missing.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  I always use <input> when I'm submitting the data between the two <form>.......</form> elements.  I'll use <button> when I want the action to be a javascript function (which can then grab the values of each <input> and pass to a javascript function), then process via Ajax instead of doing a page refresh.  Not sure its 100% best practice but it works!